# Using collections as properties of an object in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

With class module "Class1Test" as

```
Private pGreetings As Collection

Public Property Get Greetings() As Collection
Greetings = pGreetings
End Property
Public Property Let Greetings(Value As Collection)
pGreetings = Value
End Property
```

If I run the sub

```
Dim MyPhrases As Class1Test
Public Sub Test()
Set MyPhrases = New Class1Test
MyPhrases.Greetings.Add "Have a nice day"
End Sub
```

I get the a compile error "Argument not optional"

Why can't I add the string to the the collection myphrases.greetings ? Please forgive the newbie question. Just learning VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things wrong.

Collection is an object, so you must use the `Set` keyword when assigning.  Also in the `Let` procedure for consistency in naming conventions, I would use `lGreetings` instead of `Value` although that should not really matter.

```
Private pGreetings As Collection

Public Property Get Greetings() As Collection
    Set Greetings = pGreetings
End Property
Public Property Let Greetings(lGreetings As Collection)
    Set pGreetings = lGreetings
End Property
```

This will still raise an `91` error (Object variable or with block not set) because you have not instantiated the collection object.  Probably the way you should do this is in the class module's `Initialize` routine.

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pGreetings = New Collection
End Sub
```